# Creating Service with Bluetooth activation in Android

Tags: android, service, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I want to create a service in Android which will initially ask user if they want to start Bluetooth and set the Bluetooth discovery.

My question is:

1. Can I launch in the service following activities?

   ```
   if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled())
   {
       Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
       startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, 0);
   }

   // Set Phone Discoverable for 300 seconds.
   Intent discoverableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_DISCOVERABLE);
   discoverableIntent.putExtra(BluetoothAdapter.EXTRA_DISCOVERABLE_DURATION, 600);
   startActivity(discoverableIntent);
   ```
2. I want to set discoverabilty of the phone on for lifetime of application. Is it possible?
3. I want to access empty space available on SD card. How should i do it?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

1)  You cannot use that particular code because you cannot call `startActivity()` from a service.  You would need to use the following code to enable the Bluetooth:

```
BluetoothAdapter mAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
mAdapter.enable();
```

The documentation says

```
boolean enable()
```

> Turn on the local Bluetooth adapter—do not use without explicit user action to turn on Bluetooth.

So you need to be sure to prompt the user first.  Also you cannot set the device to be discoverable in the service because the only way to do that is with the `startActivity()` so you would need to do that part in some kind of a configuration Activity.

2) No, having a Bluetooth device be discoverable opens it up to a multitude of security concerns, so not only is it not possible, it's a bad idea.

3) If you want to write to the SDCard you just need to add the `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission to your manifest file and then you can use standard Java File IO.

Comment: Thanks for your help.
I think it is impossible to enable bluetooth discovery on in service.
Aneways for 3rd Question i asked 
I want to access empty space available on SD card. How should i do it?
Android Java library Java.io of android doesn't provide any function to access free space of current file system as standard Java.Io provides.
But I found StatFs class of android.os which solved my problem.

Comment: not so good advice cause google doesn't recommend to enable bluetooth without asking user first.. It can be done this way but special permission for BT administrator must be set in manifest.