# Is it possible to start my own app service when user try to enable Bluetooth/WiFi/GPRS/GPS

Tags: android, android-service

As I am new to Android world i have no idea how to start my app service when the user try to open any of these following.Bluetooth/WiFi/GPRS/GPS etc.

Comment: If you provides some details on what are you trying to achieve, people might be able better to help you.

Comment: Ok..... actually my requirement is when the user click in the bluetooth icon to enable BT, i want to start the service of my app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless you are modifying the OS, you cannot do what you want. Android does not have broadcast when the user turns on the BT, GPS, or the WiFi.

You could register with [`AlarmManager`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html) to wake you up every so often and check the state of any of these services that you care about. If neither is started, your code can go dormant again, until the next wake, when you repeat.

Note that you have to be careful how aggresive you want to be with the alarm timing. The more often you do it, the faster you'll be draining the device battery, and likelier the user will uninstall your app.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible..
See the below code:

```
NetworkInfo mobNetInfo = connectivityManager.getNetworkInfo(     ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE );
    if ( activeNetInfo != null && mobNetInfo != null )
    {
      Toast.makeText( context, "Connected: " + activeNetInfo.getTypeName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT ).show();      
      context.startService(new Intent(context,SampleService.class));
}
```

Comment: Of course, you should also mention that this code must be running at all time, and check periodically.

Comment: use this for broad cast receiver.. http://saigeethamn.blogspot.in/2009/10/android-developer-tutorial-part-11.html

Comment: Yes @FranciPenov.may i know how to do the same for bluetooth.i mean to say when the user click in the bluetooth icon how to start my app service.

Comment: see this reference.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2585332/creating-service-with-bluetooth-activation-in-android

Comment: @wolverine .. i already refereed but there is no solution.for my requirement